# The function is not working properly in python

Tags: python

I am trying to predict the future prices of petroleum but before that I wrote a simple function to see the dates vs price comparison using matplotlib visualization. However there is something wrong in the code and I am not able to find what should I pass. 
Here is the code:

```
dates=[]
prices=[]

def getdata(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
        csvFilereader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFilereader)
        for row in csvFilereader:
            dates.append(int(row[4].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[2]))
    return
def predicted_price(dates, prices, x):

    dates=np.reshape(dates,len(dates),1)

    svr_linear= SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
    svr_poly= SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
    svr_rbf= SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

    svr_linear.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_ploy.fit(dates,prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates,prices)

    plt.scatter(dates,prices, color='black', label='Data')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.rbf.predict(dates), color='red', label='RBF Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.poly.predict(dates), color='blue', label='Poly Model')
    plt.plot(dates, svr.linear.predict(dates), color='green', label='Linera Model')

    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Prices')
    plt.title('Regression')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return svr_rbf.predict(x[4]), svr_linear(x[4]), svr_poly(x[4])

getdata('D:\\android\\trans1.csv')

predicted_prices=predicted_price([dates,prices,10])
print(predicted_prices)
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-935270aaab8d> in <module>()
     38 getdata('D:\\android\\trans1.csv')
     39 
---> 40 predicted_prices=predicted_price([dates,10.2,10])
     41 print(predicted_prices)



TypeError: predicted_price() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'prices' and 'x'
```

Here is the data snapshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1JMi.png)

Comment: predicted_price(*[dates,prices,10]),

you need to expand the variables provided in the list, by adding *

Comment: You wrapped the parameters in a list, but they have to be single arguments: `predicted_prices = predicted_price(dates, 10.2, 10)`

Comment: BugHunter I tried your approach but then this error comes:Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[19. 19. 19. ... 22. 20. 23.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
predicted_prices=predicted_price([dates,10.2,10])
```

to

```
predicted_prices=predicted_price(dates,10.2,10)
```

because, `predicted_price` is expecting three arguemnts, and you giving only one which is `list`, `[dates,10.2,10]`.

Comment: I tried that but then it gives error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.

Comment: Maybe your function call should be `predicted_price(dates, prices, 10)` and according to `x[4]` in the function the parameter value `10` seems to be incorrext too.

Comment: if I pass only the parameter as predicted_price(dates, prices, 10), then the 1D error occours. I am not able to find what the probelm is.